# How to handle "lock wait timeout" errors in PHP database-based sessions using set save handler?

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I have a custom session.set_save_handler to handle database-based sessions for my application. The database table is of type innodb. I see some errors in my log file of the type, `(1205) Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction` with multiple threads, which hangs the application.

Also, I have a class which contains the session handler callbacks and have made it a singleton class:

```
 session_set_save_handler(
        array($this, "db_open"),
        array($this, "db_close"),
        array($this, "db_read"),
        array($this, "db_write"),
        array($this, "db_destroy"),
        array($this, "db_gc")
        );
```

In the "db_open" method, I set autocommit to false.

In the "db_read" method, I am doing a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` on the row with the session id. So, while performing load testing on my app. which has a lot of ajax calls making db updates as well, I noticed the `lock wait timeout` errors.

In the "db_write" method, I make an explicit "commit" or "rollback".

How do I resolve this problem? Any suggestions?

1. Should I catch these errors and issue a explicit "commit" in the
   read or write methods to release locks and retry?
2. Should I specify a higher timeout value
   for "innodb_lock_wait_timeout"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have unreleased locks because of some transactions are not completed for some reason.

Set greater value of InnoDB lock wait timeout variable: `innodb_lock_wait_timeout=300`.

Then restart MySQL Server.

If it doesn't help, maybe your table is corrupted, then refer to this article: [Recovering Innodb table Corruption](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/07/04/recovering-innodb-table-corruption/)

Comment: what if a transaction take longer than the specified timeout. My problem here is that in the session.set_save_handler, after the "db_read" method is executed and the lock is acquired on the session, it doesn't execute "db_write" method. Not sure what the reason would be..

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in your case is that you do the commit in the SessionHandlerInterface::write method. But the write method is not always executed, e.g. when using session_destroy it calls the SessionHandlerInterface::destroy method instead. So your transaction is not commited and stays open and thus blocks other concurrent requests to the same session longer than necessary. The correct approach is to commit the transaction in SessionHandlerInterface::close which is always executed at the end.

Btw, there is a PHP session handler implementation for databases in Symfony that supports different locking strategies and supports most database systems like MySQL, Postgresql, Oracle and Mssql: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/PdoSessionHandler.php

But beware that deadlocks and lock wait timeouts can still occur, but less likely. From my research there are basically three options to deal with this:

1. Catch the error and retry the transaction in the hope that the lock is released by then. When using Doctrine, have a look at https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/718 for some implementation ideas and discussions.
2. Increase the timeout, e.g. innodb_lock_wait_timeout which might help depending on the database load.
3. Ignore the deadlock or timeout by catching the exception and informing the user that he has to refresh the page for example to get his session back. Usually the lock timeout occurs when the same session is requested many times in parallel, i.e. many parallel requests of the same user. This is a non-standard user behavior and more likely to be caused by scripts or performance testing. So ignoring the error on your side and just displaying an error for the user might be a reasonable approach.